# Learning of causal structure

Tags: logic

I was wondering if someone could help me understand a few things on this wikipeida page on causality http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causality#Structure_learning related to the following possible structures with three nodes:
$$(1) \quad X \rightarrow Y \rightarrow Z \\
(2) \quad X \leftarrow Y \rightarrow Z \\
(3) \quad X \rightarrow Y \leftarrow Z$$
Wikipedia says that $(1)$ and $(2)$ imply that "$X$ and $Z$ are independent given $Y$" while $(3)$ implies that "$X$ and $Z$ are marginally independent and all other pairs are dependent". Further, "this applies even if $X$ and $Z$ have common ancestors, except that one must first condition on those ancestors."

- Is it true that all three structures imply $X$ is independent of $Z$ conditional on $Y$?
- Is the relationship between $X$ and $Z$ excluded because it doesn't affect any of the above implications?
- Does anything change if these nodes had children i.e. would we need to condition on children or do we still have the same implication that $X$ is independent of $Z$ conditional on $Y$?
- Can you provide examples for each of these structures? For example, $X$ is education, $Z$ is intelligence, and $Y$ is wages, I think would be $(3)$.

Thanks (I wasn't completely sure what tags to have).

**Edit:** I think these are the answers.

- false because (3) is not true.
- implicitly the only relationship between $X$ and $Z$ is potentially through $Y$.
- I don't think children affect anything.